# prevent a review insertion more than once in a table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am attempting to ensure that users can be able to review a book only once after they have reviewed. Below is a sample table structure

reviews table

```
id | userfk  |  bookfk
1  |  45     |   53
2  |  46     |   53  //at this point a book has two reviews from two users
3  |  45     |   53  //attempting to prevent this
```

from the above table structure, you can see that the user with id 45 succeeded in reviewing twice, hence I want to checkmate that

below is my code attempt but I am not able to check the two columns (userfk and bookfk) simultaneously

```
$hasReviewed = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxxBundle:Reviews')->findOneBy(array('userfk' => $int));
        if (!$hasReviewed) {

        }
```

Please how can I ensure that this

```
3  |  45     |   53
```

does not repeat in the table if it's already been added to the table records.

Comment: you can add a unique index matching the three element of the table directly in your database. Then try / catch the error on insert.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [UniqueEntity-Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) aswell. (You should still add a unique index on the table though!)

Comment: @Sleek You can add the unique index using doctrine annotations (there's an `indexes` parameter on doctrines `Table` annotation), the validation would happen through Symfonys UniqueEntity-Constraint though.

Comment: I am still thinking thru it, please can you show a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UniqueEntity` [validation constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#errorpath) and [unique database constraint](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) on your entity class.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"user", "book"},
 *     errorPath="user",
 *     message="This user already reviewed this book."
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(
 *    name="review",
 *    uniqueConstraints={
 *        @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
 *            name="user_book_idx",
 *            columns={"userfk", "bookfk"})
 *    }
 * )
 */
class Review
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: what does the fields (user and book) map to

Comment: They map to relation fields in your class. Add this part of your entity to the question to get more specific answer.

Comment: when I added the second line of code I got this error >>>>
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                            
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@UniqueConstraint" in class

Comment: Have you forgotten to add `use` statements on top of the class? Add class code to the question.

Comment: I used this >>> uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(    >>>>
And the error was gone.

Comment: so how do I use this to solve my problem having added the annotations to the entity

Comment: "And the error was gone" - you were right, I missed that.

Comment: "so how do I use this" - update your database schema, call validator upon entity creation (called automatically if you are using Symfony forms) and see how validator prevents from adding duplicate record.

Comment: how can I print out the exception. The catch block is not printing the exception